# Why strtotime(1st January 1970) returns -3600 instead of 0 in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

Am using `strtotime` to get seconds past `1 January 1970`, but am not understanding that why am getting `-3600` if the clock is set to `12.00AM` and I get `0` when the clock is set to `1 AM`, so what's with that `1 HOUR`? Is it an issue with the timezone?

```
echo 'I Expect 0 Here '.strtotime('1st January 1970').'<br />';
//This gives me -3600

echo 'I Expect 3600 Here '.strtotime('1st January 1970 01.00AM'); 
//This gives me 0
```

> P.S I've not set any Time Zone in my PHP file or I've not even
>   modified my .ini file (Fresh Installed XAMPP)

Update : Time-Zone : Europe/Berlin

Comment: Off topic, but rofl @ your base64 encoded email

Comment: @asprin Off-Topic comment I guess :p ;) hehe thank you anyways, I take that as a compliment

Comment: Yes it was sort of a compliment, nice out of the box thinking and humorous too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's most likely due to your local [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).
What's the output of

```
var_dump(date_default_timezone_get());
```

on that machine?
You can also check the difference between mktime and gmmktime

```
echo " mktime: ", mktime(), "\n";
echo " gmmktime: ", gmmktime(), "\n";
```

Comment: I was sure timezone was messing up things.... Thanks

Comment: +1 for mktime() and gmmktime()... :)

Answer (score 6):

Your timezone must be set to UTC+1. Midnight in your timezone happened an hour before midnight in UTC, which explains the offset of -3600 seconds.

You can set the timezone to UTC to get the expected result:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: Thank you, am using this now to reset timezone to UTC

Answer (score 5):

You need to check your time zone settings. or if you set the default_time_zone to UTC, you will get the desired result.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: 9 years later and this fixed my problem. THANK YOU lol

Answer (score 1):

add this to set timezone 'Europe/Berlin'

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
```